# Is there a reasonable "text-to-speech" solution for math papers?

Tags: mathematical-software

Is there a software which can read loudly an arXiv paper for me with a decent quality? I googled a little bit. And there are some research/software for reading texts with formulas. So the question is: are any of them good enough so that there exists an actual living mathematician who uses them without necessity? I mean not a blind one but a lazy one.

UPD: Thanks @bof for the question. I want the audio output to be comprehensible by a human. What I found in my life is that I can watch math/physics/cs youtube videos in my downtime for fun. But there is not much videos on topics of my primarily interests. So I wonder if I can at least generate an audio to listen to. It can be crappy and butcher formulas a bit but it should keep me more engaged than just a plain text.

Comment: I don't believe a human mathematician can do what you want the software to do, if the formulas are very complicated. Is the output supposed to be comprehensible by a human being, or only by another machine?

Comment: Most mathematical papers are not written to be read out loud, and many equations are not even spoken out loud by the people writing them — so no, there is probably no good software to do what you are imagining.

Comment: I always teach students that they have to be able to read a mathematical text and their solutions to exercises out loud. It's a check if they really know what is written and meant.

Comment: I was once invited to give a talk in an audience including a blind person. So, my host asked me to read loudly all I'm writing/displaying. I found this quite useful, even in other circumstances. (By the way, I believe one should ban mathematical terms that are not meant to be pronounceable, such as "rng".)

Comment: @YCor I agree on your “by the way”, but I find “rng” surprisingly comprehensible when someone says it to me. It sounds like someone starting an engine, a sound I now associate with losing my identity. Worse is the French translation “annau”, for obvious reasons…

Comment: *"But there is not much videos on topics of my primarily interests."* The youtube channel "Two-minute paper" specialises in presenting lots of papers in two minutes of videos. But it presents almost-exclusively papers about machine learning. I wish there were similar youtube channels for other topics.

Comment: Tangentially related: Euler continued creative work in mathematics after he went blind. I suspect for the visually impaired adept at braille tactile solutions are best. Can anyone provide some answers to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/3-d-printing-of-formulas-encoded-in-latex-for-the-visually-impaired?

Comment: Are you aware of the blindmath mailing list? https://www.nfbnet.org/mailman/listinfo/blindmath_nfbnet.org I remember years ago learning about different readers from that group, in particular InftyReader which seems to be still going strong: http://www.inftyreader.org/2022/06/19/about-inftyreader-group-inc/

Comment: There's also MathPlayer: https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathplayer/start . Another useful site is http://www.access2science.com/index.html (but it looks like it hasn't been updated for a while)

Answer (score 12):

Most formula-to-speech software only works with [MathML,](https://www.chhs.colostate.edu/accessibility/best-practices-how-tos/mathml/) so you would first need to convert the LaTeX you find on arXiv.

There may be an alternative, [under development](https://github.com/hutchresearch/latex2speech) for AWS:
***Tex2Speech*** takes LaTeX documents and converts them into spoken audio.

Here is the [documentation,](https://tex2speech-website.vercel.app) and this is how [it sounds](https://youtu.be/9_Mlz7RPFic?t=39) when confronted with a simple equation.

It looks promising, but I read that you need an account with AWS, which may well complicate things.